# jQuery chaining: Can everything be chained? When can we not chain?

Tags: jquery, chaining

I know that not all jQuery functions can be chained together. Is there a rule of thumb on this. When can we not chain 2 functions together.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can chain when the function returns a "jQuery object".

For example, [`.css(property, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) can be chained, as the doc says it Returns jQuery:
[image]

while [`.height()` cannot](http://api.jquery.com/height/), because it returns an integer.

[image]

Typically, the functions that returns "jQuery objects" are those which typically would not "return a value", e.g. setter methods (`.css(prop, val)`, `.addClass()`), event binders (`.click(handler)`), etc.

(Of course traverse methods (`.parent()`, `.find()`, etc.) can also be chained but the returned object will be different from the input.)

Comment: Can you give examples in JQuery where 2 functions cannot be chained.

Comment: @KennyTM, may I request you to have a look at a jquery question on a different topic here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137404/jquery-find-div-class-name-at-a-certain-position-while-scrolling ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't chain a function that returns something other than a jQuery object. For example, `attr()` with one parameter to get the value of an attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The way to distinguish is that functions which have side effects typically return jquery and can be chained where as functions with an actual return (like `.text()`) cannot.

Answer (score 2):

if in the plugin they do:

```
return this; //<--jquery object
```

at the end then u can change it with other plugins :-)

Comment: Filters oftentimes do not return the original object.