# Should I make a local variable $this when accessing $(this) multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:

```
$("#footer-create-nav li").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('footer-create-active');
    $this.siblings().removeClass('footer-create-active');
    return false;
}
```

vs how alot of my code looks:

```
$("#footer-create-nav li").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('footer-create-active');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('footer-create-active');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any advantage or disadvantage either way. ;)

Comment: I realise this may be a simplified example, but I'd suggest using chaining (`$(this).addClass('footer-create-active').siblings().removeClass('footer-create-active')`) or [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end): `$(this).addClass('footer-create-active').end().siblings().removeClass('footer-create-active');`.

Comment: Maybe. The question is does jQuery have to create a new object every time you have $(this) and can you save some CPU time by creating it once and referencing it as $this. My guess is that it's probably a little better to do $this, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @David the `.end()` there in the second example has no effect

Comment: @nickf: in that example, no it doesn't. Hm. Perhaps not the greatest example then..? Sigh.

Comment: This is a simple example and chaining sounds like a good option here but more generally it sounds like local variable caching is the way to handle most cases @Anurag's. Does jquery have some kind of internal caching though?

Answer (score 5):

It is a good practice to avoid recreating a jQuery object multiple times.

`this` represents a DOM object, and when passed to the `$` or `jQuery` function, a new jQuery object is created every single time. Caching that object once in `$this` or any other variable name of your liking avoids having to recreate the object on each invocation of `$(this)`. The benefits of this caching may depend on how many times you are calling `$(this)` and may be unnoticeable in most cases.

To get a better idea, test it out for [yourselves](http://jsperf.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You have another option. jQuery methods return the object they're operating on.

```
$(this).addClass("example")
```

would return the value of `$(this)`.

So you could write your function as

```
$("#footer-create-nav li").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('footer-create-active')
           .siblings().removeClass('footer-create-active');
    return false;
}
```

and only refer to `this` once without using another variable.

---

#### See Also

- Question: [jQuery chaining: Can everything be chained? When can we not chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5505648/1114)

Comment: `$(this).addClass("example") == $(this)` will never be true as a new jQuery object is returned every time. More generally, `$(this) == $(this)` will always be false.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. To put things in perspective, if a user triggered that function (by clicking) a thousand times on a single page, the speedup *might* balance out the additional download time incurred by the additional 20 bytes of JS code.

If you were doing a complex selector lookup in a tight loop, caching the result might be worthwhile. It definitely isn't in this case, though.

Comment: I totally disagree. Firstly, you miscalculated by not taking all optimisations into account: Let's consider the following two variations: `$(this)...;$(this)...;` vs. `var t=$(this);t...;t...;`, the weight difference is not 20 bytes, but 2 bytes. That's a packed version of the OP's proposal. Secondly, if there are already local variables being created, then we don't need to consider `var `, so now the code is actually **shorter** in the cached version. And if there are more than just two references, then it becomes even shorter... So the cached version is shorter and faster.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain it, but this jsperf appears to show that it is better to call `$(this)` each time...

http://jsperf.com/jquery-this-vs-this-vs-chain

Comment: I can explain it. Profile those executions. The **vast** majority of processing time is being spent on styling, which throws any difference in object access time out the window.

Comment: @davin, `$(this)` is always going to be a tiny fraction of the execution time, but why is re-creating it always coming up considerably faster?  Thinking maybe it's something to do with which one runs first, maybe re-ordering the cases will change it.

Comment: @davin yeah, seems whichever case is first always comes out fastest, not sure why, but this test is pointless!