# native Jquery selector VS cached object.find()

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

My fellow programmers, i'am losing my mind. I've reed many books on JS performance and all of them were saying, that it is better to cache DOM objects for future references and management and not creating new Jquery objects. It sounds reasonable.
But now my faith is shaking. Im trying to develop Code conventions in my company and i was goin to adress this problem from a performance stand point.
I've got piece of code that follows:

```
        $("#registratorType").attr("readonly", "readonly");
        $("#registratorType").attr("size", "25");
        $("#id").attr("readonly", "readonly");
        $("#id").attr("size", "25");
        $("#serial").attr("readonly", "readonly");
        $("#serial").attr("size", "25");
        $("#duration").attr("size", "25");
        $("#stoppingDuration").attr("size", "25");
        $("#speeddata").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Its not the whole thing but i think, that you've got the idea. I was going to get all this form and wrap it in the cached reference.

```
    var $form = $('#vehicleProfile');
    $form.find("#registratorType").attr("readonly", "readonly");
    $form.find("#registratorType").attr("size", "25");
    $form.find("#id").attr("readonly", "readonly");
    $form.find("#id").attr("size", "25");
    $form.find("#serial").attr("readonly", "readonly");
    $form.find("#serial").attr("size", "25");
    $form.find("#duration").attr("size", "25");
    $form.find("#stoppingDuration").attr("size", "25");
    $form.find("#speeddata").removeAttr("disabled");
```

I've tested performance in the latest chrome and was shocked! My approach was losing in 3-4 times. I mean my function runned at 42 ms, while old one was 12-14ms.
Is there REALLY any value to my method? Is my approach an anti-pattern? Help me please!

Comment: That's not what "cached reference" means.

Comment: I think it is useless to use in ID selector in `find()`, what you should do is something like var `$registratorType = $('#registratorType'); [...]`

Comment: Cache the _finds_ like `var registratorType = $("#registratorType");` then use `registratorType.attr()` as the `registratorType` variable is a jQuery Object

Answer (score 2):

Since all your selectors are id selectors, they are reasonably fast (`document.getElementById` is an `O(1)` table lookup). Yet, limiting them to a certain parent element with `find()` makes a DOM tree search necessary, which is an obvious slowdown.

"*cache DOM objects for future references*" means that you never shall apply the same selector twice. Do it once, and store it in a variable (like you did with `$form`). So instead of

```
    $("#id").attr("readonly", "readonly");
    $("#id").attr("size", "25");
```

it should be

```
    var $id = $("#id");
    $id.attr("readonly", "readonly");
    $id.attr("size", "25");
```

Since [jQuery allows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5505648/1048572) [chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7475336/1048572), the above can also be written as

```
    $("#id").attr("readonly", "readonly").attr("size", "25");
```

Btw, you actually seem to want to use [`prop()` instead of `attr()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr), and those functions accept [value maps](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) as well:

```
    $("#id").prop({readonly: true, size: 25});
```

Comment: You can also pass a map to `.attr()` to set multiple attributes at once: `$("#id").attr({"readonly":"readonly","size":"25"});` (which gives a definite performance improvement if used on a jQuery object that contains multiple elements).

Comment: So the bottom line is that there's no other drawbacks, besides the uglyness of DOM tree, in addressing elements by id other than those names are being reserved and cant be used in DOM tree. For example if i got 2 similair forms on the page i could just prefix the ID's and get better performance?

Comment: @user1929437: Yes, probably. However, if you do the caching (storing references to the DOM elements in variables) properly so that you do the DOM selection only once in the whole app runtime, you will not notice it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are finding element by their Ids. All browser have a getElementById and it's the most effective way to get an element.

Retry your benchmark with element identified by class.

Comment: So the bottom line is that there's no other drawbacks, besides the uglyness of DOM tree, in addressing elements by id other than those names are being reserved and cant be used in DOM tree. For example if i got 2 similair forms on the page i could just prefix the ID's and get better performance?

Comment: In theory yes, I read that some browsers have a performance decrease after 500 different ids but I never benched or tried it myself.